# SVN copy files for deployment

Tags: svn, deployment

Do anyone know if it is possible to make a kind of deployment package from commits earlier made.

My situation is I have just one repository for which is my master. I make my changes and commit my stuff. Now I just walk on moments through my commits and copy the files which I committed to the server. (On the server I have to navigate to the folder where the file is located and then copy)

What I would like is something like a folder with all the changed files. So I can copy the folder to the server and all the files that are changed will be replaced  and my folder structure isnt changed.

Or do anyone have a better way to deploy changes?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, "all the changed files" means all modifications you have committed, probably over several commits. If you can access the repository from the server, a simple `svn update` would do. But that requires an initial `svn checkout`, which you should still be able to do.

Next best thing is to use `rsync` in place of copy. It will copy only changes, so you do not have to specify which files to copy: just apply it to the top directory (root node) of you repository.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment is normally done by build systems. Depending on the programming languages you are using, there are different solutions available. In the simplest case, you have just to copy the files to the deployment server (PHP, HTML, Javascript, ...).

When the application is not too big, just copy everything to the server. Or checkout from your server the repository, and just update then there.

Subversion has the option to create one changes file by using `svn diff`, and applying those changes to a different working copy by using `svn patch` then. You may find working examples how to create and apply a patch on the page https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples/ If you have a different operting system on the server, different commands and installations may be necessary.

If you give more context (programming langage, what is on the server, ...), the tips may be more concrete then.